# What kind of data can be gleaned from a PDF created in LaTeX?

Tags: comments, metadata, pdfcomment, privacy

As I use LaTeX for the creation of many of my business instruments, and since I send these all over the world to different clients I just wanted to know if there are any data embedded in a PDF that might be recovered by a forensic data analyst. I often leave comments in my TeX code that I want, say, a focus group to notice while they make successive amendments to evolve the document into its final form; however, I wouldn't want these comments to be seen by the clients that ultimately receive them. Even the focus groups' comments, or any gadgets that pull data from the Internet that might reveal a source.

Comment: exiftool doesn't produce anything revealing I've noticed.

Comment: For `pdfcomment` simply use the `final` option -> so no PDF annotation will be typeset

Comment: Ordinary TeX-comments from the source code do not get anywhere near the final PDF. You can check that by decompressing the final PDF to look inside in an ASCII viewer. You might want to disable microtype and images to make the analysis of the PDF easier.

Comment: @Hanseat: How does one decompress the PDF to get the source text?

Comment: @Psychonaut : I use QPDF to decompress and decrypt PDF files. (http://qpdf.sourceforge.net) I use "qpdf.exe --decrypt --stream-data=uncompress --normalize-content=y --object-streams=disable infile.pdf outfile.pdf". If you disable microtype and images in *TeX, the source code of the PDF becomes shorter and more readable. The resulting file is still a valid PDF-file that can be viewed in any PDF-viewer.

Answer (score 3):

Some basic meta-data is included in a PDF when it is created. Most obviously here, you will have the name of the binary producing the PDF, so someone interested can find out you used pdfTeX v1.40.11 (or whatever). That might include the fact you use MiKTeX (so Windows) if you do. There is also meta-data you might add yourself, for example the author or title of the document as set up using `hyperref`. You can skip the latter and the former can be over-written by post-processing the PDF. Your font use will likely still give away TeX use even then: people outside of the TeX world are unlikely to use Computer Modern, for example.

However, what does *not* appear in the PDF is anything to do with comments or dropped material in your input (with one exception). Text that is read by TeX by doesn't make it to the output stage is not in the PDF at all. The one exception is if you clip a box or graphic: the entire box is 'there' but only the non-clipped part is shown.